# Range search on enumerables in Sitecore 8 and Solr

Tags: c#, linq, solr, sitecore

I need to do a complex range search on profile cards in Sitecore 8.
What I achieved so far:

All profile cards are indexed in Solr as lists of strings where the string in a list is a flat path like

> "Profile card name/Profile name/value"

This is the best option that came to my mind. Of course I'd like to store values as integers but have no idea how to do it with such a structure like profile card.

So, I can do direct queries in Solr which return what I expect, for example

```
q=profilecard_sm:["Card1/Influence/2" TO "Card1/Influence/5"]&rows=10
```

But I'm not sure how to do that via LINQ in Sitecore.

**Upd:**

Tried this code:

```
                var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItemWithProfileCard>()
                .Where(i => i["profilecard_sm"].CompareTo("Card1/Influence/5") <= 0) 
                && i["profilecard_sm"].CompareTo("Card1/Influence/1") >= 0))
                ;
```

But it is being serialized to

```
(profilecard_sm:[* TO "Card1/Influence/5"] AND profilecard_sm:["Card1/Influence/1" TO *])
```

Which is definitely not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it is being serialized to
>
> `(profilecard_sm:[* TO "Card1/Influence/5"] AND profilecard_sm:["Card1/Influence/1" TO *])`

I've had the same issue (although with Lucene and `int` field), which you can read about [here](http://blog.krusen.dk/between-filter-on-computed-field-in-sitecore-8/).

I think you just need to use the extension method `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.MethodExtensions.Between<T>(this T value, T from, T to, Inclusion inclusion)` from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.dll`.

Something like this:

```cs
using Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq;

var results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
    .Where(i => i["profilecard_sm"].Between("Card1/Influence/1", "Card1/Influence/5", Inclusion.Both));
```

String comparisons can be tricky though. Consider the following sorting:

```cs
Card1/Influence/1
Card1/Influence/10
Card1/Influence/11
Card1/Influence/2
Card1/Influence/3
```

Your results could end up being sorted like above, but I'm not 100% sure how Solr handles this.

Comment: Thank you!
I'm still thinking about how to do it without string comparison using strict int comparison